# Validating database condition for record existance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

On my site,
I have `textbox` where user enters URL.

Onece user enters it I show preview of that url, which contains image on that url and small description.

I fetch preview details from database.

Scenario is like this:

```
1. user enters url
2. Check whether url exist in table
3. If yes dont inset into db and fetch details like url title, desc, image
4. If not exist insert into table and then show the preview from it
```

So how first I can check whether it is present in table or not?

I have `$url` to check the condition.

```
select url from post_record where url='".$url."';
```

**I want bool or 1/0 result for this query. How can I get it?**
If True then I directly fetch record if result is 0 then I first enter the details and then show preview from table.

Is this correct way or better scenario someone can think.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_record WHERE url = ?
```

Comment: can I do: `$flag="SELECT url from post_data where url='".$url."' and id='".$id."'"`. Then perform action as per 0 or 1 value of flag?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_record WHERE url = `user_inputted_value`

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT url from post_data where url='".$url."' and id='".$id."'");
        if ($url = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            //insert url details
        }
            //After this fetch data from table to show preview
```